# Is Làng Wū Yáo's voice really cursed?

Tags: thunderbolt-fantasy

in Season 2 Líng Yá says to Lǐn Xuě Yā that the reason why Làng Wū Yáo doesn't talk is because his voiced is cursed and that when he speaks it always attracts trouble.

However is this actually true? while Líng Yá seems to speak the truth that Làng Wū Yáo doesn't want to say (like how was saying how he was lonely when they reunited with Shāng Bù Huàn) Làng Wū Yáo didn't pull on Líng Yá like he normally does